# How do I make a field increment by .5 after text is added to another field

Tags: javascript

I am working on a fillable PDF and I am trying to dynamically have a field add .5 every time a user types text in certain text boxes and remove the .5 when the field becomes empty again. The code i am trying is:

```
if (this.getField(/Friday/.test())!="") {
  event.value = this.getField("FridayDaily Totals").value+.5;
}
```

This is just my basic attempt and i could not get it to work at all.

There are two columns of field names that start with "Friday" for this one i need to exclude the ones that have a "_2" suffix and any that say "Daily Total".

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is event ?
Does your code generate an error ?

Comment: the event should be a user typing in one of the "Friday" Fields. my code generates an error and does not increment. it also doesnt filter out the Friday fields with a _2 suffix and a Daily Totals suffix.

Comment: What error does it generate exactly ?

Comment: it says the format entered does not match Friday Daily Totals

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.getField(/Friday/.test())!="") { 
  event.value = parseFloat(this.getField("FridayDaily Totals").value) + 0.5;
}
```

is this what you need ?

Comment: You are going to deal with float value , you probably should use parseFloat() instead

Comment: I know you've edited it now, but it's worth noting that with `parseInt`, [the recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) is to _"Always specify a radix to avoid this unreliable behavior"_.

Comment: When I tied it, it says NAN and wont increment.

Comment: I just tried it in the form and it still just shows NaN.